# Predictive models with different sized time series

Tags: r, prediction, arima

I'm trying to estimate an ARIMA, VAR and Neural Network models in R, to compare the quality of their predictions regarding unemployment, using the data regarding several economic indicators and COVID-19 related information which i would like to use as exogenous information. I would also like these models to use the rolling window approach, if possible.

My economic information extends from 2007 to 2021 (monthly) while the COVID data only comes from 2020, which obviously poses problems regarding the size of the time series.

Since i am trying to use rolling windows, every time I try to include COVID information i get the following error.

```
 Error in solve.default(Sigma) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.6396e-19
```

Which I assume is because the covid information is all 0's (since we are using data from 2007) and therefore the model assumes a perfect correlation for that information.

Is there any way I can combine these 2 time series (the economic one from 2007 and the covid one) in the models mentioned, while using the rolling window approach?

**dput version**

```r
structure(list(date = c("02/2007", "03/2007", "04/2007", "05/2007", 
"06/2007", "07/2007", "08/2007", "09/2007", "10/2007", "11/2007", 
"12/2007", "01/2008", "02/2008", "03/2008", "04/2008", "05/2008", 
"06/2008", "07/2008", "08/2008", "09/2008", "10/2008", "11/2008", 
"12/2008", "01/2009", "02/2009", "03/2009", "04/2009", "05/2009", 
"06/2009", "07/2009", "08/2009", "09/2009", "10/2009", "11/2009", 
"12/2009", "01/2010", "02/2010", "03/2010", "04/2010", "05/2010", 
"06/2010", "07/2010", "08/2010", "09/2010", "10/2010", "11/2010", 
"12/2010", "01/2011", "02/2011", "03/2011", "04/2011", "05/2011", 
"06/2011", "07/2011", "08/2011", "09/2011", "10/2011", "11/2011", 
"12/2011", "01/2012", "02/2012", "03/2012", "04/2012", "05/2012", 
"06/2012", "07/2012", "08/2012", "09/2012", "10/2012", "11/2012", 
"12/2012", "01/2013", "02/2013", "03/2013", "04/2013", "05/2013", 
"06/2013", "07/2013", "08/2013", "09/2013", "10/2013", "11/2013", 
"12/2013", "01/2014", "02/2014", "03/2014", "04/2014", "05/2014", 
"06/2014", "07/2014", "08/2014", "09/2014", "10/2014", "11/2014", 
"12/2014", "01/2015", "02/2015", "03/2015", "04/2015", "05/2015", 
"06/2015", "07/2015", "08/2015", "09/2015", "10/2015", "11/2015", 
"12/2015", "01/2016", "02/2016", "03/2016", "04/2016", "05/2016", 
"06/2016", "07/2016", "08/2016", "09/2016", "10/2016", "11/2016", 
"12/2016", "01/2017", "02/2017", "03/2017", "04/2017", "05/2017", 
"06/2017", "07/2017", "08/2017", "09/2017", "10/2017", "11/2017", 
"12/2017", "01/2018", "02/2018", "03/2018", "04/2018", "05/2018", 
"06/2018", "07/2018", "08/2018", "09/2018", "10/2018", "11/2018", 
"12/2018", "01/2019", "02/2019", "03/2019", "04/2019", "05/2019", 
"06/2019", "07/2019", "08/2019", "09/2019", "10/2019", "11/2019", 
"12/2019", "01/2020", "02/2020", "03/2020", "04/2020", "05/2020", 
"06/2020", "07/2020", "08/2020", "09/2020", "10/2020", "11/2020", 
"12/2020", "01/2021", "02/2021", "03/2021", "04/2021", "05/2021", 
"06/2021", "07/2021", "08/2021", "09/2021", "10/2021", "11/2021"
), unemp = c(2.25752508, -1.0989011, 2.1978022, -2.1978022, -1.0989011, 
-0.05972289, -1.08695652, -6.43115942, -1.00945017, 0, -1.07388316, 
-3.04982818, -1.96717862, 1.96717862, -1.87441425, 2.90534208, 
3.06056701, -2.02963918, 3.07130584, 2.08333333, 0, 0, 5.43478261, 
5.6763285, 3.49563046, 2.05992509, 3.33333333, 0.87912088, 0.62625546, 
4.58158018, -0.55504163, 1.06382979, 0, -1.06382979, -2.85150252, 
-4.68041237, 0.62745098, -3.38935574, 0.5026455, -0.28619529, 
-1.29525342, -2.95239548, -1.03740503, -1.76613018, -2.5210084, 
2.59222333, -1.7518872, 1.7518872, -2.6894523, 1.65289256, -3.43801653, 
-0.8503937, -2.3744125, 0.7751938, 2.29576625, 3.90578414, 4.94647471, 
1.3640873, 4.04773622, -0.92273622, 3.125, 0.45673077, 3.84615385, 
-0.95126248, 1.72049325, 0.56958309, 0.71246819, -3.64508393, 
0.92207924, -2.02585375, -1.25114155, 0.66666667, -3.8008658, 
-2.882786, -4.77313832, 0, -2.51458002, -1.30135713, -7.81499203, 
-1.75438596, -3.87759171, -2.16419816, -3.70910671, -2.12494688, 
0.46748831, -0.63842848, 0.38701623, -1.12359551, 1.43499197, 
-1.14285714, -0.07142857, 0.31385281, 1.64714631, 0.44583317, 
2.8365708, 2.38646704, -1.2987013, -1.44395079, -1.39857093, 
-1.51117827, -0.67114094, 1.15965849, 3.67636416, 2.73483341, 
-1.37718397, -0.78108941, -1.36176773, -2.05167173, 1.97459054, 
1.16173728, -0.21885522, 0.47348485, -0.86122047, -0.78740157, 
-0.78740157, -1.36727095, -1.66545543, 0.55803571, -3.31428571, 
1.3398374, -3.09467611, 0.50237969, 0.36506406, 0.38394668, 0.55958863, 
-1.04021115, -1.05878635, -1.78571429, 0.327654, -2.97315664, 
2.71485077, -0.97087379, -0.66990291, -0.23232323, -1.50994481, 
0.53174173, -1.32138858, 1.61887142, 2.80193237, -1.61616162, 
1.79704017, 3.85706183, -0.21077989, 1.03395062, 1.96428571, 
1.12781955, 4.93871665, 1.27473364, 2.65873016, -1.42857143, 
-2.73641851, 6.98011599, -1.47058824, 2.94117647, 1.49253731, 
1.49253731, -2.98507463, -4.54545455, 0.06784261, -5.97014925, 
22.3880597, 10.78697422, 3.42657343, -6.75086108, -4.25146992, 
-9.26916221, -4.41176471, -0.02131287, 3.09617918, 0.21645022, 
4.61309524, 7.29166667, -26, -9.18518519, -4.65221319, 3.17073171, 
4.21052632, 3.28947368), regist_un = c(-7.6, -8.1, -10.4, -13, 
-12.2, -10.8, -10.2, -11.3, -12, -13.2, -13.8, -12.7, -11.6, 
-11.4, -8.2, -3.6, -1.6, -2, -0.5, -0.7, 0.5, 2.9, 6.6, 12.1, 
17.7, 23.8, 27.3, 27.6, 28.1, 30.1, 28.7, 29.1, 29.1, 28.2, 26.1, 
25.1, 19.6, 18.1, 16.1, 14.6, 12.7, 10.3, 9.6, 8.9, 6.4, 4.4, 
3.3, -0.5, -1, -3.5, -5, -5.4, -6, -4.4, -3, -0.3, 3, 6.7, 11.7, 
14.4, 16.6, 19.8, 21, 20.8, 24.5, 25, 26.3, 23.4, 22.5, 19.6, 
17.4, 16.05866431, 14.1343296, 11.04394749, 11.07092871, 9.66638699, 
6.80821419, 4.99845882, 3.21403698, 2.00992748, -0.01381295, 
-0.82689753, -2.83078075, -4.69352568, -5.22666645, -6.07571945, 
-8.30308904, -9.4986526, -10.86351863, -11.10348947, -10.1911332, 
-11.56954866, -12.86335954, -13.57419377, -13.31634168, -12.71367749, 
-13.78692468, -14.3833581, -14.16732657, -12.93820022, -12.73630773, 
-12.91458502, -14.04113868, -12.63480706, -10.48461147, -7.99771938, 
-7.25281958, -7.35380587, -4.68547808, -2.62950703, -1.82217091, 
-3.44938365, -4.66108643, -6.57689723, -7.04795734, -8.83698741, 
-9.49043411, -11.59763744, -13.07912754, -13.26308777, -15.34204052, 
-18.01521541, -19.89096413, -19.19477791, -18.26531051, -16.35403878, 
-16.14554408, -16.34837215, -17.53504461, -16.81810893, -16.32660251, 
-16.00691286, -17.02626382, -16.57334233, -16.61939724, -18.99258341, 
-20.51560419, -20.5844694, -19.149043, -17.49773014, -17.38241663, 
-17.23274637, -16.0328503, -15.58626266, -15.29940386, -15.14205448, 
-14.5670108, -12.85161091, -10.29016682, -10.0720839, -10.00068018, 
-11.10920973, -10.23871997, -8.6402685, -8.42184435, -8.61357235, 
-7.91941687, 2.99152725, 22.12769269, 34.00159255, 36.37735545, 
37.00494467, 34.50234942, 36.14288275, 34.50948107, 30.17574135, 
29.55791318, 32.38134753, 36.84886013, 25.91626159, 8.04566645, 
-1.65087765, -7.08027492, -9.47650638, -9.99850976, -12.4400864, 
-12.85751101, -13.15709526), electr_cons = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.52573055, -13.77356375, -2.91314706, -8.07503923, 
5.64741668, 2.14652942, 8.96942648, -12.90473041, 6.7462353, 
-1.99320589, 3.5519951, 3.96085785, 2.90812218, -3.01852589, 
-0.72990857, 6.62024931, -4.03278316, 15.15581887, -5.80240675, 
6.15355971, -8.9434497, 7.09174981, -3.03231017, 5.99309871, 
0.12505412, 7.98920263, 4.97957359, -13.41437565, 3.1251824, 
-19.61649962, 8.42404224, 3.9274678, -0.69310101, -6.20882422, 
2.92246113, 0.84784002, -5.54698038, -0.34784001, -2.23860664, 
2.52721219, 1.51556136, 0.11030442, -6.11617537, -0.35384086, 
3.73968268, 1.36305933, -4.2866283, -3.01881185, 8.07963944, 
5.51292808, -4.35131302, 3.6602547, -6.44713838, 1.39859892, 
1.30415104, -1.60930464, -0.40894902, -0.56603623, 3.40891108, 
-1.80100326, -5.44803444, -6.44187786, 38.45132631, -4.07719031, 
0.61965483, -1.49863173, 3.30109363, 1.19224911, -2.92700391, 
16.92568044, -15.15157455, 3.48316945, -1.00483719, -40.57315028, 
9.7659042, 4.78461676, 0.28264713, -0.87145969, -3.86558313, 
-0.0679219, 2.45947602, -9.41849532, 8.07657479, 3.93419348, 
1.94861355, 52.56477551, -54.55955271, -3.99890956, 4.60669488, 
1.67468875, 0.32376412, -0.80237405, -4.03956352, 1.8608071, 
-0.74354869, -6.79369666, -2.74137491, 5.6219074, 5.13307485, 
2.09278167, -8.97792005, 0.23895157, 2.34350504, 2.01565156, 
0.34461909, -5.39315134, 3.70375643, 1.35911336, 0.14440375, 
-10.59505494, 2.44997231, -3.43575023, 8.45149168, 1.82580942, 
-5.09746181, 0.54849722, -0.40588822, 2.90913923, -2.59092777, 
2.87179578, 3.5472478, 5.50635214, 3.45884957, 0.5574311, -9.17310051, 
-2.3069345, 1.01792404, 3.39829408, 2.18975374, -3.29888986, 
3.36520805, -6.06857013, 3.69912561, -5.88831257, -5.59447201, 
6.93463825, 5.18518235, -4.45047426, 3.48886956, -4.22410882, 
0.36229398, 4.38850288, 2.44283293, -4.13337598, 0.07853854, 
0.33111425, -1.50291612, -10.73449339, -2.31367763, 6.06925576, 
7.25078064, -1.2508886, 0.69265168, -1.6952393, -5.45510355, 
10.36136532, 0.81292421, -5.78213732, 0.29608406, 8.58995306, 
3.33976066, -16.05532167, 4.59091993, 2.96362702, -1.21232785, 
0.44224015, 4.78743418), inflation = c(-0.3, 0.1, 0.4, -0.4, 
0, -0.1, -0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, -0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.3, -0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 
-0.3, 0, 0.1, -0.7, -1.1, -0.6, -0.7, 0, -0.7, 0.1, -0.8, -0.3, 
0.1, 0.3, -0.6, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0, 0.8, 
0.1, 0, 0.3, -0.1, 0.2, 1.2, -0.1, 0.4, 0.1, -0.3, -0.4, -0.3, 
-0.2, 0.7, 0.5, -0.2, -0.3, -0.2, 0.2, -0.4, -0.2, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 
0.3, -0.2, -0.8, -0.2, 0.2, -1.7, -0.2, 0.5, -0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 
-0.4, -0.6, 0.1, -0.3, 0.1, 0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, 0.3, -0.2, 
0.1, -0.5, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 0, -0.4, -0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 
-0.2, -0.1, 0, 0.2, -0.2, -0.1, -0.3, 0.4, -0.5, 0.3, 0, -0.1, 
0.3, 0, 0.1, -0.1, 0.4, -0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, -0.2, 1, -0.7, -0.7, 
0, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, -0.1, -0.2, -0.5, -0.4, 0.1, -0.5, 1.1, 0.6, 
0.2, -0.9, 0.5, -1, 0.1, -0.3, 0, 0.3, -0.1, 0.1, -0.6, 0.4, 
-1.4, 0.6, -0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, -0.3, -0.4, -0.2, -0.5, 
0.8, -0.3, -0.1, -0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, -0.2, -0.2, 0.6, 
-1.1, 1.7, 0.2, 0, 0.5, 0.8), indust_prod = c(-2.572274344, -2.787547763, 
2.430571433, -3.345301558, -0.463876872, -4.282068938, -1.120792803, 
1.572826809, 5.587675149, -4.689662112, -4.039000653, 6.048760143, 
3.054565546, -8.324475243, 8.938629302, -8.359749373, 1.285898904, 
2.787686994, -1.18689554, -1.044345864, -5.377152698, 0.417765217, 
-2.016437912, -6.076899004, 0.004832982, 6.553009253, -3.861674081, 
2.856277, -0.305740286, 3.884000992, 0.228026533, 3.160838283, 
0.718539054, -0.177278754, 5.861419366, 1.635627332, -0.233559319, 
1.656666214, -3.416861953, 3.08593964, 0.219887065, -5.252665393, 
2.67414747, -3.078208264, -1.786603334, 5.055713134, -0.487827087, 
-1.085759889, 1.558281917, 1.522276844, -0.649720104, -2.25624012, 
-3.000400858, 1.287503915, 2.146782202, -2.414634004, -0.710817622, 
-2.037943864, -3.422580841, 2.574492816, -0.989720019, -3.140953611, 
-2.00903906, 5.044475953, 2.421105335, 1.312884435, -0.423167539, 
-1.618876184, 0.749480391, -0.067574147, 0.665361763, 2.736011629, 
-0.984538393, 2.734504118, 3.689697632, -4.285546756, -1.453623444, 
-3.036406761, 0.371745852, 5.268465577, 2.014992273, 0.230769423, 
1.479245498, -0.601620521, 0.435743581, -6.919825179, 3.973589167, 
-1.18054296, 1.009209474, 3.4645508, -4.268359859, -1.38055936, 
1.398352479, -1.380441077, -0.945043656, -3.070867046, 2.286824653, 
4.15932548, -0.885666142, 1.66749454, 1.079797346, 1.268988373, 
-3.757792572, 3.297688911, 0.757515843, -3.344176468, 0.937671829, 
1.942358369, -0.363516768, -2.258151209, 1.602633167, -3.43640148, 
1.319433782, -3.471816444, 6.680682523, -3.215319966, -4.672113236, 
6.216354428, 0.969772263, -0.213391145, -3.34142316, 5.648021789, 
-8.289444236, 8.300362011, -2.663437754, 3.039228136, 3.239437295, 
-6.66030595, 1.185659472, -1.499248124, -3.292614657, 2.681309878, 
-0.579981109, 0.867209022, 2.022041722, -6.479958297, 1.680604654, 
-0.873272771, -2.875794511, 3.56198993, 0.706252639, -3.546626564, 
1.706203079, -1.238940266, 0.694831062, -4.576557295, 5.589573409, 
1.887484409, -6.283451003, 3.968287705, -4.024275523, -0.142379113, 
3.389769739, 5.34662785, -1.707063421, -1.962359729, 1.648794981, 
-5.778920692, -8.801594747, 6.391085381, 3.735161238, 0.512586559, 
1.347387952, 0.083401305, -0.958210945, 0.28448621, -0.398402291, 
0.174892606, -2.923332835, 9.40208252, 8.440250585, -5.118029161, 
-4.652533609, -1.031496063, 0.253718285, 0.116959064, -0.767472053, 
-2.656293514), construction = c(-5.97969161, -4.79269684, -5.74581431, 
-5.80595875, -3.91928599, -4.68384075, 2.11180124, -2.08333333, 
-2.12510024, -2.80786201, -2.94938222, -2.5189924, -3.04, -3.39592489, 
-2.50302786, -4.54176805, -5.77544426, -5.52825553, 2.83860503, 
-6.58756137, -7.37402704, -6.9748246, -9.32238193, -11.64889253, 
-10.35478548, -10.21505376, -11.09730849, -8.41121495, -8.65837977, 
-11.66016472, -15.14195584, -9.46123522, -8.97832817, -9.40550133, 
-10.00905797, -8.58867224, -10.86056144, -11.60755412, -10.75919888, 
-11.03896104, -12.57625528, -8.83218842, -15.24163569, -12.48185776, 
-12.97376093, -13.36924584, -11.67589331, -11.93499238, -10.22199277, 
-11.04742053, -10.96033403, -13.3472367, -11.27214171, -12.86329386, 
-14.03508772, -13.0458817, -14.40536013, -15.65856416, -14.52991453, 
-13.49480969, -15.12363427, -15.58289397, -18.22977726, -17.74969916, 
-16.57592257, -16.86226065, -14.66836735, -16.52892562, -16.1121983, 
-15.8847185, -16.46666667, -19.2, -19.85094851, -17.4184594, 
-16.27240143, -14.55742502, -15.88107324, -15.15601783, -15.8445441, 
-16.22239147, -15.08553655, -13.14741036, -14.44533121, -14.68646865, 
-11.3271344, -14.45378151, -9.93150685, -11.81506849, -10.94827586, 
-10.07005254, -8.25932504, -6.18181818, -6.04395604, -6.05504587, 
-3.91791045, -0.87040619, -4.09914204, 0.09823183, -3.8973384, 
-2.23300971, -2.80735721, -2.72638754, -1.839303, -3.87596899, 
-3.89863548, -4.4921875, -6.69902913, -5.75609756, -3.77733598, 
-5.69185476, -3.85756677, -4.27010924, -5.37848606, -3.5035035, 
-6.01577909, -3.83064516, -2.63691684, -2.04498978, 0.52029136, 
3.10559006, 2.58264463, 1.144641, -0.30864198, 0.20746888, 2.31578947, 
1.34854772, 2.51836306, 2.72536688, 1.66666667, 1.67014614, 3.51966874, 
2.10843373, 1.91339376, 3.08641975, 3.81836945, 4.24430642, 3.90946502, 
3.48004094, 4.81064483, 4.18367347, 4.4057377, 3.28542094, 1.7, 
1.08161259, 1.97628458, 3.79241517, 5.96421471, 3.17775571, 2.27722772, 
3.26409496, 2.44140625, 1.76297747, 2.15897939, 8.41012196, -0.16302847, 
0.76178712, -4.69372663, -17.51199295, -45.16320079, -36.28914654, 
-16.06074568, -4.87295907, 7.5668007, 3.72748757, 7.02862225, 
3.38149083, 1.75109309, 4.74865906, 14.84745984, 34.803423, 100.52114863, 
67.60757235, 30.44713435, 18.17227737, 11.63694169, 9.69843425, 
4.74314833, -4.52314658), exports = c(24.96318942, 23.36969334, 
22.92995604, 10.65726657, 16.4160009, 15.06347523, 7.05135338, 
15.02299212, 19.0326442, 18.98558329, 3.33296617, 23.07105097, 
24.1601689, 19.72166595, 27.16602809, 24.3702412, 14.56065717, 
23.81003502, 12.51014556, 1.73165902, -13.84780944, -22.58391171, 
-20.80753018, -33.06565254, -36.85899284, -37.79190796, -39.34913459, 
-33.38661304, -27.85334908, -28.37492746, -23.27801369, -13.6431818, 
6.74411365, 11.84361899, 13.51797098, 20.8751474, 22.95402278, 
28.37464897, 21.54264152, 8.61516289, 3.13570326, 4.20220684, 
8.75273789, 5.92066231, 6.95366577, 4.26020533, 11.40501619, 
9.87457947, 21.13174127, 16.42066897, 31.89439842, 33.06799105, 
34.07732157, 29.29939609, 27.02846164, 20.81549686, 14.50583432, 
16.11199422, 5.25642553, 5.67979421, 5.03884106, 5.91383786, 
-6.92432553, -4.54670446, -5.43453018, -11.06914116, -4.30401515, 
-5.89475834, -6.20354881, -5.22134237, -1.09985899, 9.43369798, 
1.66688812, 1.20138491, 6.90689277, 7.75020233, 10.13668917, 
11.30827244, 9.29930475, 10.9321974, 9.07936123, 15.05633842, 
13.19202501, 5.4705525, 6.82591085, 2.44716859, 4.11748271, 5.06863218, 
6.22577349, 6.12185947, 0.58671313, -3.10270985, 1.18732102, 
-8.2784308, -6.9219884, -15.34433626, -14.14267264, -15.499663, 
-17.52534249, -13.08561877, -13.30851885, -14.85330263, -14.60224224, 
-11.87824448, -10.99332931, -13.12023756, -13.1469306, -6.67165565, 
-4.86353483, -1.18866693, 5.19617018, -5.56720735, -1.31601522, 
2.27149134, -0.32052319, 6.34015708, -2.21439899, 8.54617508, 
7.90296929, 8.97464479, 8.46001663, 14.8780712, 0.80639894, 12.94240637, 
3.50598117, 9.14630966, 19.69171985, 15.802644, 16.51140186, 
21.66597738, 20.28010486, 25.27245738, 22.10541531, 15.94575338, 
26.38566548, 13.20690115, 17.00548484, 12.09162042, 0.06482127, 
2.03901271, 0.44242727, -9.82586651, 0.27668163, -2.78174059, 
-2.82866966, -3.82970378, -5.71082564, 2.43947926, -5.13803015, 
-5.57470758, -5.42985341, -2.92568853, 3.29088281, 0.70260049, 
-5.31805275, -3.60733326, -1.34953732, -13.82572968, -43.79388438, 
-37.96950775, -25.84963925, -17.45358624, 1.37712882, -6.52424698, 
-1.90571756, -7.56995756, 4.05542391, -3.88890971, 0.22947427, 
18.0580403, 83.71922617, 69.97805207, 37.59500165, 29.96692408, 
15.45334076, 19.1358433, 18.69987106, 1.361784), new_licences = c(-8.68185938, 
-0.02872738, -4.63917526, -1.28723796, 6.61294804, 22.56276492, 
0.7781103, 4.79877409, 10.14401124, 8.24945593, 12.81146637, 
9.55541727, 22.9280397, 5.57950192, 13.32309582, 5.15754737, 
-8.87412041, -4.33625964, 4.81079247, 6.37217177, -6.40984757, 
-3.33605579, 37.89418817, -43.23130325, -42.15352673, -42.12746655, 
-33.9205377, -33.62858734, -23.67129034, -20.50889878, -14.90326237, 
-12.50180871, 3.46190541, 1.31288184, -17.85106785, 61.84546971, 
53.12063809, 86.83179182, 33.04076778, 46.80088462, 62.54917879, 
18.35461489, 13.50837139, 15.08185877, 1.04729285, 19.36104696, 
61.72782699, -9.18395384, -12.57976299, -20.58231247, -11.10426044, 
-23.56363636, -34.11195205, -29.70589684, -31.85551458, -33.86262394, 
-40.44064924, -48.64559819, -59.99715485, -47.36404205, -48.59228363, 
-49.05969361, -41.7394923, -27.49762131, -37.00874636, -35.13210456, 
-33.07096298, -30.93970668, -19.15289482, -25.34798535, -43.46550498, 
0.89093261, 8.91046074, -0.19703412, -4.26190476, -5.38995126, 
17.88392113, 17.14563526, 12.84454245, 15.91945886, 23.0810884, 
23.51044441, 35.77606542, 31.90428714, 40.30863376, 47.04904406, 
53.12111415, 36.55008422, 23.55712603, 30.67416767, 26.05438854, 
31.72750712, 29.72943247, 33.01929625, 37.87352328, 27.84796458, 
35.64994785, 41.8951385, 21.94250447, 33.10840226, 33.91801716, 
9.71134166, 21.90931404, 30.04017719, 16.31199661, 14.13943169, 
10.39986559, 17.71959459, 25.98727895, 31.75638663, 6.44645711, 
13.57863178, 10.93394077, 0.59826311, 12.84306453, 10.63138715, 
8.87090896, 23.54216507, 29.26495206, 7.82034725, 4.63800277, 
-1.80663693, 17.80530531, 13.51986946, 6.23716632, 12.3673104, 
12.0950324, 6.38739706, 6.44081414, 6.66263238, 0.41205557, -2.8280543, 
10.1373204, 7.07467283, 13.80775358, -0.3255401, 5.34750745, 
13.59549283, 28.0137388, -14.04051962, -12.215373, -12.25462385, 
-5.28197913, 7.40258851, -9.21869735, -10.48961104, -1.44190387, 
-3.61384459, -3.27574344, -7.6398978, -18.62443557, 13.99263957, 
12.13098309, 6.03905341, 9.71096119, -8.04004081, 7.45041892, 
-57.44578313, -86.98451778, -74.73596198, -56.22999407, -17.50379692, 
-0.14475271, -9.42437148, -12.58866381, -27.8902439, -19.59833014, 
-30.46522915, -58.98435572, 19.84711212, 438.70498363, 190.21076468, 
70.96424702, -18.97560655, -35.80575018, -18.2011224, -22.68440675, 
-7.59343819), investm = c(9.59206261, 10.09104451, 8.49259555, 
11.05912367, 11.33035356, 10.69893187, 9.27221449, 6.36319052, 
5.1145808, 3.14675108, -2.0583252, -5.9801462, -8.54458193, -11.85690298, 
-12.73704068, -15.30334665, -16.51488054, -18.55445193, -18.78407228, 
-20.33141371, -23.20479413, -23.70413199, -25.82349247, -23.49151634, 
-23.20331483, -21.76656318, -19.69767216, -16.1163604, -15.56801204, 
-10.63893647, -6.90914634, -1.33860382, 5.00317034, 9.14637266, 
13.66111398, 14.90618555, 16.27492141, 18.9726911, 17.81129998, 
11.93953654, 9.97602683, 6.72450506, 3.35538125, 1.22492917, 
-0.25529345, -3.58030117, -5.66383325, -5.99451638, -5.59778107, 
-8.22207902, -8.75620416, -6.82634766, -7.76850362, -8.81317285, 
-10.30877298, -12.31016477, -12.44698993, -11.49249967, -9.6953666, 
-10.58305192, -9.65103885, -8.93856304, -8.31371275, -8.81656192, 
-7.08877565, -5.92517826, -3.13301918, -0.90715848, 0.17047088, 
0.71130641, 3.09817756, 6.3772002, 6.05805695, 4.99307084, 4.93907049, 
7.50839619, 8.21051614, 7.46196337, 6.59668824, 6.44846351, 4.4735673, 
3.33064046, -0.20557392, -0.17865147, -0.07705874, 1.55447287, 
0.59002986, -0.47146863, 0.62804213, -2.08346753, -2.73661788, 
-3.90829617, -3.78220665, -4.01170424, -5.17638734, -6.16018899, 
-5.69641901, -6.49065187, -5.75373139, -6.16938142, -10.39770764, 
-7.95466132, -7.83823783, -8.7925605, -7.90867493, -5.97676105, 
-5.228471, -6.84892555, -8.8243345, -9.50405058, -10.14943257, 
-10.02532808, -8.25385595, -7.41211911, -6.72331539, -4.65132561, 
-3.88085377, -5.35115101, -3.6992884, 3.41808435, 5.01032011, 
6.4338955, 7.44842984, 7.96282188, 10.42036183, 9.85846999, 10.3384518, 
12.3886042, 13.55244814, 14.4281047, 12.93327424, 7.14080025, 
6.37943542, 4.68820186, 5.38710032, 4.61464096, 3.14205599, 2.9423131, 
2.15746296, 0.09387282, -2.38577599, -2.97124266, -4.32001028, 
-4.33596506, -3.36175388, -1.65514585, -1.1147413, -1.1116245, 
0.03453284, 1.51801102, 1.97354903, 3.29586522, 4.83238917, 5.70220137, 
7.46051222, 7.48040345, 6.30281751, 0.14703508, -0.15754408, 
0.73361141, 0.474155, 0.46358707, 1.64385862, 1.15369522, 0.67754708, 
4.63841367, 6.78461903, 8.58994132, 10.23754398, 17.32260776, 
19.2077649, 20.72874275, 21.76681016, 22.19165981, 23.17276241, 
23.11683188, 23.85460849, 20.34415852), household_consupt = c(0, 
0, 1.359168191, 0, 0, -0.342789739, 0, 0, 1.790564565, 0, 0, 
-0.482967554, 0, 0, -1.762057837, 0, 0, -0.536837331, 0, 0, -4.302408991, 
0, 0, -4.488751839, 0, 0, -1.381433473, 0, 0, 0.30585643, 0, 
0, 3.227950235, 0, 0, 5.377633558, 0, 0, 1.854863297, 0, 0, -0.352069414, 
0, 0, -0.701775487, 0, 0, -3.526502117, 0, 0, -2.191789397, 0, 
0, -0.956817085, 0, 0, -2.394047662, 0, 0, 1.250192652, 0, 0, 
-0.572344375, 0, 0, 0.753471833, 0, 0, 0.070143601, 0, 0, -0.298510806, 
0, 0, 3.154164092, 0, 0, 0.883890768, 0, 0, 2.625083331, 0, 0, 
0.256046586, 0, 0, -0.856863549, 0, 0, 0.590803335, 0, 0, -0.813925723, 
0, 0, 0.125528578, 0, 0, 1.468506379, 0, 0, -0.670352866, 0, 
0, -0.362744845, 0, 0, 1.32210668, 0, 0, -1.215018014, 0, 0, 
0.331687133, 0, 0, 1.532560625, 0, 0, -0.533138522, 0, 0, -0.422657587, 
0, 0, 0.037693685, 0, 0, -0.657257657, 0, 0, 0.489966584, 0, 
0, 0.938809848, 0, 0, -0.343317849, 0, 0, 0.626641626, 0, 0, 
0.067372918, 0, 0, -0.634514601, 0, 0, 0.004316699, 0, 0, -0.456951802, 
0, 0, -3.945597519, 0, 0, -16.828812208, 0, 0, 12.869510817, 
0, 0, -1.316414045, 0, 0, -1.582469509, 0, 0, 26.887239149, 0, 
0, -14.346872459, 0, 0, 2.145073044, 0), covid_total_cases = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 236.490662, 29.76642, 29.664615, 
21.193137, 13.588659, 30.217886, 87.020465, 110.973322, 38.789711, 
74.173149, 11.664696, 2.132837, 1.797567, 1.506289, 3.587828, 
10.127144, 7.154014, 3.020636, 1.99873, 5.189378), covid_total_vaccinations = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 964.859996, 
163.568194, 94.43678, 87.634082, 73.551864, 47.399777, 42.470628, 
20.985756, 8.109421, 1.48542, 7.961336)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-178L))
```

Code:

```
VAR_data_Total = data

f = function(data){
  m1 = vars::VAR(data[,1:10], p=3, exogen = data[,11:12])
  s1 = summary(m1)
  
  return(s1$varresult$unemp$coefficients)
}

zoo::rollapply(VAR_data_Total, width = 41, FUN = f, by.column = FALSE)
```

Comment: Code and sample data (made up if necessary) to reproduce the issue would be helpful.

Comment: I have provided a sample in my edit

Comment: Very nice, but please use `dput` to put the example in such a form that we can *easily* copy and paste it into our R session.

Comment: Am getting this error using my `dput` above in your post. Which do you have as factors? Can you make your own `dput`? Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" :
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: I have tested the dput version in R and it works

Comment: @dcsuka have you been able to import the data?

Comment: No, I get this error: `Warning in storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels` Try starting a fresh R session.